# Should I put actions dropdown in the right side of breadcrumbs?

Tags: actions, breadcrumbs

I'm designing a user page for the back-office web application and thinking of the best place to put the actions(change user password, remove user).

The solution I came up with is to put them under the dropdown menu and move the trigger button in the opposite side of breadcrumbs.

Is that a good practice? Since the breadcrumbs is a component which located at the navigation area of the page and actions is a component which logically should be at the content page area but I'm putting it in the navigation side.

If that's a wrong idea, I'm opened to the suggestions(Use it as plain buttons without dropdown, move to another place etc..)

Here it is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try to establish a pattern that's learnable to users whenever possible. Use contrast to increase visibility in the view.

In you mock, you're talking about a specific screen, with 2 actions on a **User** object.

The view appears to be a **detail** view. Your main concern seems to be discoverability about what's possible.

The placement for actions on an object in a detail view is fairly common. You can be more explicit by using a label marked actions, so users don't have to interpret the meaning. Enhance that with some visual design to give it contrast in your view.

[image]

Since this is a list of actions, it can scale to other **detail** pages that have more elements and more actions. At that point, you have a discoverable pattern with consistent placement and scope across other detail views.

Comment: the main concern is different a bit. I'm afraid that putting "Actions" dropdown in the navigation area(where breadcrumbs are) is not a good thing since it's part of a page and should probably somewhere below

Comment: sorry if my answer was unclear. I moved the 'actions' dropdown a little bit. If you have truncated page titles, you can fit it alongside there. My answer focused a little more on visibility. I agree with aligning below the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

Top right might be a bit far for users to find.

I would stick with familiar approaches such as having the password field with an edit option triggering the editing flow.

As for Remove User, bury it under update option.

[image]

Comment: The approach of having "Remove user" action in the bottom of the page is great. But putting the password field I don't think will work since it's not representing a simple field in the database and requires confirmation, that's why I'm considering putting it in a separate area(for example inside of a modal window)